# How to add table inside react-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using `react-draft-wysiwyg`.I try to finding to apply **`TABLE`** but not found way anything. Pls help me , if you saw them before. Thanks all

Comment: Could you update with your code? What did you try?

Comment: `import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import { convertToRaw , convertFromRaw , EditorState , convertFromHTML , ContentState  } from 'draft-js';

<Editor
                                                editorClassName="editor-class" 
                                                editorState={editorContents[0]}
                                                onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChangeExecutive.bind(this,0)}
                                                />
`
This is my source

Comment: in your question please, btw with more detail you will get the answer sooner